# How do I move an element down one in source with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an ordered list with list items inside.

```
<ul id="fruit">
    <li id="listI1">banana</li>
    <li id="listI2">apple</li>
    <li id="listI3">orange</li>
    <li id="listI4">grape</li>
    <li id="listI5">strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

I know that `$('#listI1').appendTo('#fruit')` would send that item to the bottom of `fruit`, and in the same manner using `prependTo()` I can send `listI5` to the top.

How do I instead move `listI1` just below `listI2` or `listI5` just above `listI4`?

Comment: You could use jquery's `.eq()`  perhaps to get the index and do something with it

Comment: [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `insertAfter()` to insert `listI1`  just below `listI2` and use `insertBefore()` to insert `listI5` just above `listI4`.

**insertAfter()**

```js
var elem = $('#listI1');
elem.insertAfter('#listI2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fruit">
    <li id="listI1">banana</li>
    <li id="listI2">apple</li>
    <li id="listI3">orange</li>
    <li id="listI4">grape</li>
    <li id="listI5">strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

**insertBefore()**

```js
var elem = $('#listI5');
elem.insertBefore('#listI4');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fruit">
    <li id="listI1">banana</li>
    <li id="listI2">apple</li>
    <li id="listI3">orange</li>
    <li id="listI4">grape</li>
    <li id="listI5">strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery's `after()` function. http://api.jquery.com/after/

```
$('#list2').after($('#list1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the methods you are after are [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) depending on which syntax you prefer. The following two lines will do the same thing:

`$('#list2').after($('#list1'));`

`$('#list1').insertAfter($('#list2'));`